# ArcGIS calculating values from multiple tables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I'm trying to build a model in ModelBuilder where I collect the sum of the "Shape_Area" field in three different feature classes, and add the total to a field in a fourth feature class. I used Summarize By Attributes to collect the sum of the area for each of the feature classes.

How can I take these sums into the field calculator to get the total of the three sums?

Comment: Are you using the ModelBuilder from ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: You will need to create a join from the 4th feature class to your summary table, to do an attribute join you will need a unique field that is common between the feature class and the table. Spatial joining isn't an option between a feature class and a table but it may help transfer a unique attribute from your other feature classes to the 4th, from there you should be able to do an attribute join. **Don't use FID from a shapefile as your unique field**.

Comment: thanks for responding, I will try it and get back if it works